# Date/Time field issue while porting from Oracle 9i to PostgresDB

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I have 455 tables in Oracle 9i DB needs to port that to Postgressql DB 9.4 Version.
I did used navicat premium version.Except date/time column which has tables are ported full fledge.
But the problem i have faced with certain tables have date/time field which does not allow to port from oracle to postgres?

Comment: to try helping you It would be nice having some error or code. you provide number of tables, but no details on the problem you meet

Comment: "*have date/time field which does not allow to port*" I have no idea what that should mean. Postgres a real `date` type (unlike Oracle) without a time and a `timestamp` that contains both date and time.